# Do android services have the `onSaveInstanceState` equivalent?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager

I want to save some data into a file/db **immediately** without using a foreground service in the background (as I don't want to draw user's attention), when users leave the relevant `Activity`.

I was thinking of spawning a background service and if my background service fails to execute it's work due to system pressure, I can enable `START_STICKY` and check if the intent is null when the service is restarted. Only maybe then turn the service to foreground service or, schedule a job (through `WorkManager` or `AlarmManager`, depending on how important the data is for users). However, neither of them is quite what I want. Foreground service will make the notification appear, and managers will schedule the work (not immediate).

Has anyone any idea about how to do that?

Comment: "I want to save some data into a file/db immediately without using a foreground service in the background (as I don't want to draw user's attention), when users leave the relevant Activity." -- have your viewmodel update your repository, using whatever reactive stuff you have going (e.g., RxJava, coroutines), or a simple single-thread `Executor` if nothing else. IOW, this does not seem significantly different than how you would be updating your local data store in other situations (e.g., user clicks a "Save" button).

Comment: Forgot to mention. I don't want my sync request gets lost once the system kills my process when I send my application in the background.

Comment: Local disk I/O is usually pretty quick on modern hardware. Your data cannot be very large, if you were planning on relying on an `Intent` to somehow carry it around. So, have you benchmarked this I/O to see how long it will take?

Comment: Not really. About the data: though it is not large indeed, this still seems like a valid corner case, right?

Comment: If the I/O is likely to be sub-second, I definitely wouldn't worry about it. If it might be more than a second but definitely under a minute, a plain background service should be fine without any extra shenanigans like the `START_STICKY` stuff (and that was the wrong value anyway, as the `Intent` is always `null` -- you probably wanted `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`). Local I/O is relatively easy, in that the disk isn't going anywhere (contrasted with network I/O, where many things can prevent the I/O temporarily).